# What is the best way to persist a hierarchy with an abstract class w/o a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a simple inheritance model:

```
public abstract class Base {
    int id;
    string name;
}

public class Derived1 extends Base {
   int valueD1;
}

public class Derived2 extends Base {
   int valueD2;
}
```

How should I map the classes (with JPA annotations) so that I have separate tables for Derived1 and Derived2 (Table per concrete class), and **no** table for Base.

Should I use @MappedSuperclass, or @Embeddable (and skip inheritance), or @Inheritance?

Comment: Don't do such things, you'll have problems in the future.

Comment: @RomanC what do u mean?

Comment: I mean that if you want Table per concrete class then you don't need abstract classes.

Comment: @RomanC so what do u suggest? A superclass is handy in Java

Comment: I don't remember what kind of problem I had in the past, but I moved ids to the subclasses and it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use @MappedSuperclass, and define distinct tables for each entity, IMHO,

But it depends on if you will most likely query for the parent class or if you use both derived entities for themselves, without having the need to query two tables.

Comment: Can the mapped superclass have the primary key ID?